# 'docker-compose run app yarn add raven-js' does not install package in npm_modules

Tags: reactjs, docker, yarnpkg

I am developing React app which is running in docker container.
When I added new library to the project by

```
docker-compose run app yarn add raven-js
```

and started again the container

```
docker-compose up
```

I get following error

```
Starting app ... done
Attaching to app
app    | yarn run v1.3.2
app    | $ node scripts/start.js
app    | Starting the development server...
app    |
app    | Failed to compile.
app    |
app    | ./src/index.js
app    | Module not found: Can't resolve 'raven-js' in '/usr/src/app/src'
```

Checking inside package.json:

```
...
    "raf": "3.4.0",
    "raven-js": "^3.24.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
...
```

but inside node_modules inside the docker container raven-js folder is not present.

index.js:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import Raven from 'raven-js';
    import './index.scss';
    import App from './App';
    import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
...
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Configuration for DEVELOPMENT 
# base image
FROM node:9.6.1

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY yarn.lock /usr/src/app/yarn.lock
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json

RUN yarn
RUN yarn add global react-scripts@1.1.1

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

# start app
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
```

I removed yarn.lock and installed again all packages by
`docker-compose run app yarn` but it doesn't help.
Any suggestions how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

After several trials I found following work around solution,
when docker container is running I am connecting to container and rebuilding the project as follows:

```
docker exec -it b42 /bin/bash  

yarn
```

where b42 is example number of container

Most probably the root of the problem is somewhere in docker configuration, anyhow above solves the problem any time when I get error message that some package is not found despite of prior installation of that package.